# How to pass variables from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have now all my javascript code in my views (PHP). But I want to seperate that (for  deleting duplicate code).
I am currently using CodeIgniter framework and currently I use functions like this :

```
$(function() {
    $("#serialNumber").autocomplete({
         source: "<?php echo site_url('manage/getSerials'); ?>",
         change: function(event, ui) {
             if (!ui.item) {
                 $(event.target).val("");
             }
         },
         focus: function(event, ui) {
             return false;
         }
    });
});
```

However you can't use javascript variables inside php.

So should I create for each link a variable and use it like that in my javascript or use the javascript in a seperate php file or is there a better way around it ?

The answer with help from ToniTornado :

First make a function like this :

```
function getURL(link) {
    var site = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>";
    site += "/" + link;
    return site;
}
```

Include that in your collection where all your jquery, css files are
Then use the function like this (jQuery) :

```
$(function() {
    $("#serialNumber").autocomplete({
         source: getURL('controller/function'),
         change: function(event, ui) {
             if (!ui.item) {
                 $(event.target).val("");
             }
         },
         focus: function(event, ui) {
             return false;
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to pass many variables from PHP to Javascript is to collect them in a PHP object, convert the object to JSON and print it out in a script tag on your website.

In your controller:

```
$config = new stdClass();
$config->site_url = site_url('manage/getSerials');
$config->user_name = 'David';
```

...pass the `$config` var somehow to your view.

In your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var MyConfig = <?= json_encode($config); ?> // global var "MyConfig"
</script>
```

It will generate this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var MyConfig = {
    site_url: "what/your/function/returned",
    user_name: "David"
  }
</script>
```

And finally access your vars like this in your Javascript files:

```
console.log(MyConfig.site_url)
```

The global Javascript var `MyConfig` has the additional benefit of having all your dynamic variables namespaced in a Javascript object.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think this is one of the best ways to pass the functions. The problem is that you need to make like double URL's to the same function.

Comment: You're welcome. What do you mean by "double urls"?

Comment: You need to declare the functions before loading the view and use the variable instead of hey I want this function right now ! :)

Comment: more clean than mine. +1

Comment: Ah ok now i got it. :) To call a PHP function from Javascript "directly" you need an AJAX-request every time you want to call the function - I'm not sure if you would want to do that.

Comment: Just another idea... What does the site_url() function look like in PHP? Is it feasible to copy its functionality in JS?

Comment: site_url is a relative URL (depending on location running). I use it to access my controller in JS.

Comment: What about defining a var "base_path" and then use it like `MyConfig.base_path + "/sub/dir"`?

Comment: @ToniTornado Good Idea, but if you have a large application with alot of requests to get data I think it's not so good to have an ajax request before each call to a controller

Comment: I tried this before but it doesn't seem to work. But now it does work probably due to a small typo Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can create a php array and add a new item every time you create a link for your js function like:

```
$links['refence'] = site_url('manage/getSerials');
```

*refence = name of js variables or name of property of js object that contain all your link.

now at the and of your all view (before ) you may create this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var refLink = {
        <?php foreach($links as $key => $link): ?>
            <?php echo $key; ?> : <?php echo $link; ?>,
        <?php endif; ?>
    }
</script>
```

(if you use this prop ondom ready) the obj `refLink` are evalued like:

```
var refLink = {
     link1 : "yourpath/action",
     link2 : "yourpath/action2",
     link3 : "yourpath/action3",
}
```

and now you not need to use `php` inside complex JS but all inside a single js.

```
$(function() {
            $("#serialNumber").autocomplete({
                source: refLink.link3,  //link3 is the key of you php array. 
                change: function(event, ui) {
                    if (!ui.item) {
                        $(event.target).val("");
                    }
                },
                focus: function(event, ui) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```

It's a way... maybe not the best... but... if you want try.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . Maybe the best way is just to include in a php document in script tags.

Comment: you can create a view that responds to a url like "base path / config.js" that return a text/javascript header that contain the javascript object or a JSONP... but all depends of your PHP app architecture. I think... the best way is the one that is easiest for you but thought.

Comment: You can simply call json_encode() on $links instead of this foreach loop.

Comment: @ToniTornado YES. That's true but I don't know what is the best way to do this in terms of server work. If you know... you are welcome. :D

Comment: This won't make any measurable difference.

Comment: Alright... so your way is more clean than mine.

Comment: Thanks ;) But the basic idea is the same in our answers!

Comment: yep yep... i think is a good way if David cant create a view that responde to a url like `path/config.js` where the body of response is a JSONP or JS Object with all js configuration.